# Unhandled Runtime Error, Error: React Context is unavailable in Server Components (next.js)

Tags: reactjs, next.js

[image: unhandled error]

Facing this unhandled error, I was following an older tutorial of next.js, trying to create a login page with google auth. What can I do?

```
    import { useSession, signIn, signOut } from "next-auth/react"

export default function Home() {
  const { data: session } = useSession();
  if(!session){
    return(
      <div className={'bg-blue-900 w-screen h-screen flex items-center'}>
      <div className="text-center w-full">
        <button onClick={()=>signIn('google')} className="bg-white p-2 px-4 rounded-lg">Login with Google</button>
      </div>
      
    </div>
    )
  }

  return (
<div>logged in {session.user.email}</div>
  )
}
```

Comment: did not resolve the issue but I decided to start again on nextjs12 instead of 13

Comment: You could have kept Next.js 13, or even 14 and just choose the pages' router during creation.

Answer (score 1):

In **nextjs** `useSession` works only in *Client Components* not in *server Components* .

You have to add `"use client"` at the top of your file above your imports.

**NOTE  :** defining a "use client" in a file, all other modules imported into it, including child components, are considered part of the client bundle.